# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.Parameter name:length,System.String.Substring(System.Int32 startIndex,System.Int32length)

Tags: c#

```
          foreach (var i in credentials)
        {
            string line = i.ToString();
            if (i.ToString().Substring(0, i.ToString().IndexOf(":")).Equals(usernameInput.text) &&
                i.ToString().Substring(i.ToString().IndexOf(":") + 1).Equals(passwordInput.text))
            {   isExists = true;
                break;
            }
 }
```

this show error "length cant be less than zero.plz  guide me how to put startindex and string length in this .

Comment: `i` doesn't contain a `:`.

Comment: instead of substring you can directly check `if(line == $"{usernameInput.text}:{passwordInput.text}")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)